# where do get ADT 18 for eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

My eclipse updated ADT to 20, which I believe sucks, and I want do get 18 back. But can't find where to download it from.

In here https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ it offers only the version 20.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download this file:

http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-18.0.0.zip

Then when going to install new software, click 'Add...' followed by 'Archive...' and then select the folder.

Answer (score 2):

You can get it from

http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-18.0.0.zip

To get any other version, just replace 18 with another version. Hope this helps!