# where to download Android SDK 18

Tags: android, sdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [where do get ADT 18 for eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046779/where-do-get-adt-18-for-eclipse)

Any ideas where to download Android SDK 18 , the new 20 from here http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html will work only with ADT 20, which i believe sucks.

Thanks.

Comment: (Try this)[http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html#]

Comment: You have already asked this question barely an hour ago here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13046779/450534 and selected an answer too! Why would you post the same question again?

Comment: @SiddharthLele That was about ADT. This is SDK tools I am guessing.

Comment: @SiddharthLele, that was about ADT, which I installed and now it asked for an corresponding SDK. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get version 18 from the below link. Hope this helps!

http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r18-windows.exe

change 18 to other versions to download the respective installers.

Comment: That link is invalid. Where did you get it from?

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean v18 of the SDK tools. Find the name of the tools package and use it in front of the URL.

For example, the **windows version** is at:

```
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r18-windows.zip
```